# Kubernetes: Affinity depending on Azure Availability Set

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

**Requirement**

Kubernetes in Azure uses *Availability Sets* as the default availability strategy.

I can specify the kubernetes `nodeSelector` attribute to select a specific node.

```
kind: Pod
... 
spec:
  ...   
  nodeSelector:
    ???
```

**Question**

Can I specify the `nodeSelector` rule to use a node in a specific *Availability Set*?

I could label the pods manually after creation. But is there an automatic solution?

Comment: Rather than specifically selecting nodes you might be able to achieve the same with `podAntiaffinity` within a selected `agentpool` (which does get labeled and maps to the AvailabilitySet). So ensuring pod X won't schedule more than once on the same node `name`, unless nothing else is available. This works well for replicated pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371867/1909531) was right. It does not make sense to use availability sets in my pod affinity rules as an availability strategy.

But I solved my problem by using availability zones for my affinity rules:

```
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
            - westeurope-1
```

Answer (score 4):

first of all, this question makes no sense, as with availability sets you can only have 1 node pool with AKS (and your tags mention AKS) (at least supported). but still, nodes have labels that look like this:

```
agentpool=pool_name
```

so your node selector would looks like this:

```
  nodeSelector:
    agentpool: pool_name
```

Comment: Very useful, but where is this documented? (I mean the default AKS `agentpool=pool_name` label)

Comment: I'm not sure this is documented anywhere explicitly, but thats the way it is. to confirm it is as such you can take a loot at the aks engine code base

Comment: Created a docs issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/78665

Comment: but you can also pass in additional labels to the nodepools if you wish so